# Soap WebService to Soap Webservice Call

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, jelastic

I have Created two Java SOAP Webservices in Netbeans. Basically each service is a different Web App having its own war file. I Invoke the first WS from Java Client and The second service is invoked from the First service. These are working perfectly fine when I am using 3 machines to run in a LAN. Client, Service1 and Service2 on 3 Seperate machines. Now I have deployed the services on Jelastic Cloud. The first service gets invoked from Client. But when the First service is trying to invoke the second service I get the below Error. 
I copy pasted the wsdl url in browser. The WSDL is available and accessible. So I am sure this is not an issue of Server not being deployed or wrong URL.

Please Help.

```
Failed to access the WSDL at: http://multipurpose.jelastic.servint.net/ProxyServer/ProxyServerService?wsdl. It failed with: 
Connection refused.
at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:265)
at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:246)
at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:209)
at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:178)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:364)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:322)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:231)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:212)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:208)
at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:119)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:92)
at server.proxy.ProxyServerService_Service.<init>(ProxyServerService_Service.java:50)
at server.tpa.pack.TPAServerService.setServer1UrlAtProxy(TPAServerService.java:1164)
at server.tpa.pack.TPAServerService.setServer1Url(TPAServerService.java:911)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:93)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(InstanceResolver.java:250)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:88)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:419)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:868)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:422)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.invokeAsync(ServletAdapter.java:225)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:161)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:197)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:81)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:997)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:851)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1301)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)
at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.createReader(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:999)
at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.resolveWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:400)
at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:231)
... 61 more
```

Comment: http://multipurpose.jelastic.servint.net/ProxyServer/ProxyServerService?wsdl currently reports 404 from glassfish. Are you sure the URL responds as expected when accessed via browser?

Comment: I have temporarily undeployed the project. I can turn it on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GlassFish in [Jelastic](https://jelastic.com/) is listening **8080** port, and all requests to **80** port are redirected to the **8080** via the iptables rules. 
Your requests are going trought local interface and **PREROUTING** rule isn't used by the loopback interface.
We have added **OUTPUT** rule for your case and all work as it should for now.
Also, we have created an improvement to add **OUTPUT** rule by deafault. As a workaraund you can specify **8080** port in your requests from local GF nodes: *http://multipurpose.jelastic.servint.net:8080/ProxyServer/ProxyServerService?wsdl*.

Comment: This is working now with the above workaround Thanks :)